# Getting Touchpad to Behave on Dingo 19.04

Tags: touchpad, laptop, 19.04

Recently bought a GeoBook 3X. A surprisingly nice little intel based ultrabook. Getting it set up for Ubuntu for my wife (by request). After figuring how to circumnavigate the UEFI/bios to get it installed I am left with the problems of the Touchpad which really isn't working properly at all. Which is a shame because everything else has just worked (tm) Ubuntu feels snappier than Windows did on the same machine. I'll do whatever it takes to get this sorted!

Anyway enough of my waffle. Touchpad isn't dead it's just not behaving. 
Experiencing the following issues. (Fine on Windows)

1) You'd think it was dead - it isn't
2) You have to exert way more pressure to register movement than Windows OR have to increase the amount of surface area of the finger on the touchpad by lying it flatter against the surface.
3) the buttons dont seem to work correctly - I had some success fiddling with settings but because of the other issues it's hard to be sure if issue 2 isn't causing it.

The Touchpad is showing up as 
SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Touchpad 
under xinput.

The touchpad itself may have extra gesture features (I couldn't care less about) perhaps there something weird in this area.

Ultimately this feels like it could be a config issue - but other reports suggest updating the kernel so there could be more at play here.

What I've tried

Tried installing and uninstalling xf86-xorg-input-synaptics meh :(
Tried fiddling with both libinput and synclient properties and im not convinced all of the options are doing anything , but can confirm the option to turn it on or off works. 
I've fiddled with the settings of 
FingerHigh & FingerLow - which 
(as I understand it are to do with pressure thresholds) 
I've tried sensible values and random ones no discernable difference.

There's not a lot of info about this on the internet so I might as well be the Hero and ask in the right place!

Happy to poke around and compile things if neccessary.

Please help me get this working!

Ubuntu 19.04

5.0.0-24-generic 
quad core P4 N4200 (spectre_v1 & v2 bugs present sadly)

PS I've just spotted

```
event4  -  SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Touchpad: kernel bug: clickpad advertising right button
```

I'll post more data where needed.

Comment: Ok so last night i managed to get this machine into a boot - loop . ( Thats what happens if USB is blocked ,the keyboard is locked and grub is set to reboot to bios.) I decided to get a refund in the end so Im afraid theres no point in taking this any further. Real shame though.